# VPS resource alerts for "dcachesize" and "oomguarpages"

Tags: web-hosting, server, vps

I am running 1 vbulletin forum, 1 wordpress, 2 opencart (e-commerce) and 3 simple html sites on my VPS.  Sometimes I get warnings like these:

- `Dec 04, 2014 12:11:29 AM    Resource    Resource dcachesize green alert on environment 113 example.com current value: 22256812 soft limit: 26210000 hard limit: 26210000    Green zone  dcachesize`
- `Dec 04, 2014 12:18:29 AM    Resource    Resource dcachesize yellow alert on environment 113 example.com current value: 22499725 soft limit: 26210000 hard limit: 26210000   Yellow zone dcachesize`
- `Dec 04, 2014 12:11:29 AM    Resource    Resource oomguarpages yellow alert on environment 113 genesiseries.com current value: 168249 soft limit: 191146 hard limit: 191146  Yellow zone oomguarpages`
- `Dec 04, 2014 12:13:30 AM    Resource    Resource oomguarpages green alert on environment 113 genesiseries.com current value: 116764 soft limit: 191146 hard limit: 191146   Green zone  oomguarpages`

My CPU usage:

```
0.7% CPU
Load Average: 0.72, 1.06, 0.86
RAM: 524.6 MB  39%  
Free: 819.4 MB  
Total: 1.3 GB
```

What can be happening? what is "dcachesize" and "oomguarpages"?

Comment: Which log file are these warnings appearing in?

Comment: On virtuozzo power panel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I experienced similar issue on one of the VPSes I have with [RoseHosting](https://www.rosehosting.com/). I contacted their technical support and they fixed the issue for me and everything has been good since then.

Anyway, when I asked what was the problem, they said that it was related to the *dcachesize* limit which represents the maximum size of filesystem-related caches limit for my server, such as directory entry and inode caches.

As for the *oomguarpages* parameter, from the [vzctl(8)](http://openvz.org/Man/vzctl.8) man page:

> Guarantees against OOM kill. Under this beancounter the kernel accounts the total amount of memory and swap space used by the container’s processes. The barrier of this parameter is the out-of-memory guarantee.

so, as I also experienced multiple OOM scenarios on one of my VPSes before I upgraded my RAM, I guess this is a limit which saves some processes of being killed by the kernel in OOM situations.